# Bokeh web server app at localhost to html file

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, bokeh

I have been working with `bokeh web server`.

I created a web app, using my own data and following this example: https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/master/examples/app/movies/main.py

I already finished the script and everything went ok. I can see the result using this command: `bokeh serve --show main.py`

The modules I used to create the web app were:

```
from os.path import dirname, join
from pandas import Series, DataFrame
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.layouts import layout, widgetbox
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, HoverTool, Div
from bokeh.models.widgets import Slider, Select, TextInput
from bokeh.io import curdoc
from scipy import stats
import numpy as np
import pandas
```

However, my goal is to upload the result to my `gh-pages` branch on github.

How can I save the result from `bokeh` as html file in order to use it in a web page?

I tried using `show` from `bokeh.plotting`, but it shows the localhost path as the command `bokeh serve --show main.py` did.

Is there an other command I could use?

Any suggestions are appreciated! Thanks in advance.

## UPDATE

I use this code to get a solution. With this code I got a html file as output, but it needs to be improved.

```
from os.path import dirname, join
from pandas import Series, DataFrame
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.layouts import layout, widgetbox
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, HoverTool, Div
from bokeh.models.widgets import Slider, Select, TextInput
from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh.resources import JSResources
from bokeh.embed import file_html
from bokeh.util.browser import view
from jinja2 import Template
from scipy import stats
import numpy as np
import pandas

csvdata = pandas.read_csv('Alimentacion.csv', low_memory = False, encoding = 'latin-1')

# Convert amount field into int()
def str_to_int(mainList):
    for item in mainList:
        newList = [(int(item.replace('$', '').replace(',', '')) / (1000000)) for item in mainList]
    return newList

# Call str_to_int function
csvdata['CuantiaInt'] = str_to_int(csvdata['Cuantía'])
mean = np.mean(csvdata['CuantiaInt'])

# Assing colors to each contract by mean
csvdata['color'] = np.where(csvdata['CuantiaInt'] > mean, 'red', 'blue')
csvdata['alpha'] = np.where(csvdata['CuantiaInt'] > mean, 0.75, 0.75)

# Replace missing values (NaN) with 0
csvdata.fillna(0, inplace=True)

csvdata['revenue'] = csvdata.CuantiaInt.apply(lambda x: '{:,d}'.format(int(x)))

estados1 = [line.rstrip() for line in open('Estados1.txt')]
estados2 = [line.rstrip() for line in open('Estados2.txt')]

csvdata.loc[csvdata.Estado.isin(estados1), 'color'] = 'grey'
csvdata.loc[csvdata.Estado.isin(estados1), 'alpha'] = 0.75

csvdata.loc[csvdata.Estado.isin(estados2), 'color'] = 'brown'
csvdata.loc[csvdata.Estado.isin(estados2), 'alpha'] = 0.75

csvdata['z score'] = stats.zscore(csvdata['CuantiaInt'])
csvdata['sigma'] = np.std(csvdata['CuantiaInt'])

date_time = pandas.DatetimeIndex(csvdata['Fecha (dd-mm-aaaa)'])
newdates = date_time.strftime('%Y')
newdates = [int(x) for x in newdates]
csvdata['dates'] = newdates
csvdata['Dptos'] = csvdata['Loc dpto']
csvdata['Entidad'] = csvdata['Entidad Compradora']
csvdata['Proceso'] = csvdata['Tipo de Proceso']

axis_map = {
    'Cuantía y promedio': 'z score',
    'Cuantía (Millones de pesos)': 'CuantiaInt',
    'Desviación estándar': 'sigma',
    'Fecha del contrato': 'dates',
}

desc = Div(text=open(join(dirname(__file__), 'alimentacion.html')).read(), width=800)

DptosList = [line.rstrip() for line in open('locdpto.txt')]
ProcesosList = [line.rstrip() for line in open('tipoproceso.txt')]
EntidadesList = [line.rstrip() for line in open('entidades.txt')]

# Create Input controls
min_year = Slider(title = 'Año inicial', start = 2012, end = 2015, value = 2013, step = 1)
max_year = Slider(title = 'Año final', start = 2012, end = 2015, value = 2014, step = 1)
boxoffice = Slider(title = 'Costo del contrato (Millones de pesos)', start = 0, end = 77000, value = 0, step = 2)
dptos = Select(title = 'Departamentos', value = 'Todos los departamentos', options = DptosList)
proceso = Select(title = 'Tipo de Proceso', value = 'Todos los procesos', options = ProcesosList)
entidades = Select(title = 'Entidad Compradora', value = 'Todas las entidades', options = EntidadesList)
objeto = TextInput(title='Objeto del contrato')
x_axis = Select(title = 'X Axis', options = sorted(axis_map.keys()), value = 'Fecha del contrato')
y_axis = Select(title = 'Y Axis', options = sorted(axis_map.keys()), value = 'Cuantía (Millones de pesos)')

# Create Column Data Source that will be used by the plot
source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=[], y=[], color=[], entidad=[], year=[], revenue=[], alpha=[]))

hover = HoverTool(tooltips=[
    ("Entidad", "@entidad"),
    ("Año", "@year"),
    ("$", "@revenue" + ' Millones de pesos')
])

p = figure(plot_height=500, plot_width=700, title='', toolbar_location=None, tools=[hover])
p.circle(x = 'x', y = 'y', source = source, size = 7, color = 'color', line_color = None, fill_alpha = 'alpha')

def select_contracts():
    dptos_val = dptos.value
    proceso_val = proceso.value
    entidades_val = entidades.value
    objeto_val = objeto.value.strip()
    selected = csvdata[
        (csvdata.dates >= min_year.value) &
        (csvdata.dates <= max_year.value) &
        (csvdata.CuantiaInt >= boxoffice.value)
    ]
    if dptos_val != 'Todos los departamentos':
        selected = selected[selected.Dptos.str.contains(dptos_val) == True]
    if proceso_val != 'Todos los procesos':
        selected = selected[selected.Proceso.str.contains(proceso_val) == True]
    if entidades_val != 'Todas las entidades':
        selected = selected[selected.Entidad.str.contains(entidades_val) == True]
    if objeto_val != '':
        selected = selected[selected.Objeto.str.contains(objeto_val) == True]

    return selected

def update():
    df = select_contracts()
    x_name = axis_map[x_axis.value]
    y_name = axis_map[y_axis.value]

    p.xaxis.axis_label = x_axis.value
    p.yaxis.axis_label = y_axis.value
    p.title.text = '%d contratos seleccionados' % len(df)

    source.data = dict(
        x = df[x_name],
        y = df[y_name],
        color = df['color'],
        entidad = df['Entidad'],
        year = df['dates'],
        revenue = df["revenue"],
        alpha = df['alpha'],
    )

controls = [min_year, max_year, boxoffice, dptos, proceso, entidades, objeto, x_axis, y_axis]

for control in controls:
    control.on_change('value', lambda attr, old, new: update())

sizing_mode = 'fixed'

inputs = widgetbox(*controls, sizing_mode=sizing_mode)

l = layout([
        [desc],
        [inputs, p],
    ], sizing_mode=sizing_mode)

update()

curdoc().add_root(l)
curdoc().title = "Contratos"

with open('../Contratos/Alimentación/alimentacion.jinja', 'r') as f:
    template = Template(f.read())

js_resources = JSResources(mode='inline')
html = file_html(l, resources=(js_resources, None), title="Contracts", template=template)
output_file = '../test.html'

with open(output_file, 'w') as f:
    f.write(html)

view(output_file)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your app makes calls to actual python libraries (e.g. `numpy` and `pandas` that you show above) in any of its event callbacks (in fact, if it even has any `on_change` callbacks *at all*), then it is not possible to make a "standalone HTML file" (i.e. that can be simply uploaded in isolation) that will reproduce its functionality. Specifically: browsers cannot execute python code, do not have `numpy` and `pandas`. The main purpose of the Bokeh server is to be *the place where python code can run*, in response to UI events. You will need to find some actual server somewhere to run and host a Bokeh server.

If you have the Bokeh server hosted somewhere permanently, and are asking how to embed a Bokeh app running on it into a static page on `gh-pages` then the answer is to use `autoload_server` or alternatively embedding the server app URL with an `<iframe>` works perfectly well.

Comment: unless, OP actually created this beautiful graphic which he wants to put up on gh-pages as a static web graphic. Just another possiblity.

Comment: Bokeh does not generate static output programmatically. This is a long standing feature request, but difficult to implement. We are working on a solution involving Chrome headless, but it is not ready yet. If the OP just took a screen shot and is asking who to embed a PNG on `gh-pages` that's not a Bokeh question.

Comment: That was deep for me. I just looked up what bokeh is and installed it on my box. Great work if you are involved in it. :)

Comment: Let us know if we can answer any questions. The [public mailing list](https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/?pli=1#!forum/bokeh) is also a great resource.

Comment: @bigreddot Thanks. I came out with this question since I saw the code example from this dataviz https://demo.bokehplots.com/apps/movies also used modules as `import numpy as np`, `import pandas.io.sql as psql`, and `import sqlite3 as sql`.

Comment: Hi @bigreddot. I edited the question. After a few hours I got a html file as output, but the `models.widgets` such as `Slider, Select, TextInput` need to be improved. I added all the code I used. Am I missing something?

Comment: @estebanpdl the examples on demo.bokehplots.com are all hosted and live running a bokeh server always running on an AWS instance. For "needs to be improved" that is too vague for me to say anything whatsoever.  I have no idea what you would consider to be an improvement.

Comment: Hi, @bigreddot. Thanks! What I meant with 'needs to be improved' is that I got a html file with all information `inline`, and I can see now the result in that file, but when I want to use the filters, the chart is not updated. So I think that maybe I am not using the parameters I should use. I saw this example: https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/tree/master/examples/howto/interactive_bubble and the app works great without a server, and it returns a html file that could be uploaded to a `gh-pages`.

Comment: Your callbacks contain ***actual python code***. That can only run in a Bokeh server. What you are trying to do is not possible, without running and hosting a Bokeh server. It is not possible to render a pure static HTML/JS document and have python callbacks function, because browsers have no way to run python code. The server is the place where python callbacks can execute (that's the entire reason it exists).

Comment: Great! Thanks, @bigreddot I have a better picture now.