# Plot a normal distribution using a callback/widget to specify the range

Tags: javascript, python, bokeh

I am trying to plot a normal distribution where you can specify the range. I need to return this as html. I used some code from [this example](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/interaction/callbacks.html#customjs-for-widgets). What do I need to do make the callback work? Now I get `list not defined` as error when I check the developer-tools in my browser.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats

from bokeh.layouts import column
from bokeh.models import CustomJS, Slider
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show, ColumnDataSource

output_file("slider2.html")
N = 500;a = 0;b = 1
x = list(np.linspace(a, b, N))
z = list(scipy.stats.norm.pdf(x,abs(b-a)/2,abs(b-a)/6))
source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=x,z=z))

plot = figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=400)
plot.line('x', 'z', source=source, line_width=2, line_alpha=0.3)

callback = CustomJS(args=dict(source=source), code="""
    var d2 = source.get('data');
    var b = cb_obj.get('value')
    d2['x'] = list(np.linspace(a, b, N))
    d2['z'] = scipy.stats.norm.pdf(x,abs(b-a)/2,abs(b-a)/6);
    source.change.emit();
""")

slider = Slider(start=1, end=10, value=1, step=.1, title="upper limit", callback=callback)
layout = column(slider, plot)
show(layout)
```

Comment: CustomJS code must be written in pure Javascript. You have used python functions in here, so thats why the console log says list not defined. You can write purely python callbacks, but those require the use of the bokeh server.

Comment: Okay the issue seems to be the [use of numpy and pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39111369/bokeh-web-server-app-at-localhost-to-html-file/39111847#39111847)  in the callback function. The `Math.sin()`-function in the linked example comes from javascript

Comment: Correct, pandas and numpy are python libraries and not known to javascript.  Answering your own question is great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a some of tinkering, I managed to get the result I was looking for.

To summarise the discussion above: *CustomJS code must be written in pure Javascript*. Therefore using any python functions will cause errors in the html-file. However Javascript functions can be used.

```
callback = CustomJS(args=dict(source=source), code="""
   var d2 = source.get('data');
   var b = cb_obj.get('value')
   for (i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
      x[i]=Math.random()*b
   }
   x.sort(function(a, b){return a - b})
   source.data['x']=x
   z=d2['z']  
   var first=(1/Math.sqrt(2*Math.PI*Math.pow(b/6,2)))
   for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      z[i] = first*(Math.exp(-Math.pow((x[i]-(b/2))/(b/6),2)));
   }
   source.trigger('change');
""")
```

Comment: Note that in recent versions of Bokeh this should change to `souce.change.emit()` (the syntax above will continue to work for some time still)

Comment: Also note that if you *do* need to run real Python code, that is precisely what the [Bokeh Server](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/server.html) is for.

Comment: I did learn a lot about Bokeh during this task. Just wondering is it possible to combine `BokehJS` with e.g. `jstat.js`? I was trying to load `jstat.js` into the html somehow in the hope it would be loaded together with `bokeh.js`. But I couldnt find any option which does that.

Comment: `CustomJS` callbacks just execute JS code so it seems possible in principle, but I don't know anything at all about `jstat.js`, so there may be fiddly details to figure. Sorry I cant offer more help.

Comment: No Problem. But there is no (simple) optional statement in 'bokeh' which lets you load '.js'-libraries before 'CustomJS' is executed?
In my failed trial, I included `<script src="my.javascript.library.js"> </script>` into an html-template for the `file_html`-function from bokeh. Though in short that didn't work, because that `template`-option in `file_html` is (maybe) for other stuff or gets called 'too late'.

Comment: There is an open issue on GH for an "init" callback, which might be what you are asking about.